# How do I make an internal redirect in Silex / Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have users getting auto-generated when they login via social media. I don't get their email so I want to make it that when they land on `/whatever/page/after/login` they see a screen that's like "Just enter email to continue on!"

I took a look at http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/sub_requests.html and I'm either misreading or thinking I'd need to do it within a `Silex\ControllerProviderInterface`. I want this behavior to be for any request. Meanwhile if I make all my providers extend one, I'm not sure of the right way to cut out of a parent's `connect` without botching everything.

I also tried re-initializing everything similar to the answer here [Unable to overwrite pathInfo in a Symfony 2 Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477408/unable-to-overwrite-pathinfo-in-a-symfony-2-request).

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
$app
->before(function (Request $request) use ($app) {
      $token = $app['security']->getToken();
      $app['user'] = null;

      if ($token && !$app['security.trust_resolver']->isAnonymous($token)) {
          $app['user'] = $token->getUser();


          if (!$app['user']->isVerified()) {
            $request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', '/signup');
            $request->initialize($request->query->all(), $request->request->all(), $request->attributes->all(), $request->cookies->all(), $request->files->all(), $request->server->all(), $request->getContent());
          }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to do is create a new `Request` object with the correct values and then tell that app to handle it.

If you don't care about preserving the request params from the original request then you can strip a lot of the extra stuff out.

```
$app
->before(function (Request $request) use ($app) {
      $token = $app['security']->getToken();
      $app['user'] = null;

      if ($token && !$app['security.trust_resolver']->isAnonymous($token)) {
          $app['user'] = $token->getUser();


          if (!$app['user']->isVerified()) {
            $subRequest = Request::create('/signup', 'GET', $request->attributes->all(), $request->cookies->all(), $request->files->all(), $request->server->all(), $request->getContent());
            $subRequest->request = $request->request;
            $subRequest->query = $request->query;
            return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
          }
      }
    });
```

Comment: There are some crazy things going on. It infinite loops so I had to add `if (!$app['user']->isVerified() && preg_match( '/signup/', $request->getRequestUri() ) === 0) {` because I couldn't figure out what the requestUri is at that point due to the infiniteness. I now also have a weird 500 but that could be my fault. I'll have to tweak when it's not midnight and then mark yours as good ;)